# Jquery Autocomplete display names and send Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How can I change my jQuery autocomplete to use an Id instead of my values?
I would like to display the list of names but send a search using the Id value. Now it is working properly with the names but I think it will be more effective if it tries to find a unique value as an ID.

```
$.getJSON('Dashboard/CompaniesWithId', function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (i, item) {
    sellers[i] = item.Name;
    sellersID[i] = item.Id;
  });
}).error(function () {
  console.log("error loading seller to the autocomplete");
});

$("#searchSeller").autocomplete({
  messages: {
    noResults: 'No sellers with this name',        
  },
  minLength: 2,
  delay: 500,
  source: sellers,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a hidden field and use the on select event to set the value of the hidden field to the selected id

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

you can also use selection data with format `[{value: 'value', label: 'label'}]` but using this way, the field will show the id instead of the label

```js
var availableTags = [
      {id: 1, label: "ActionScript"},
      {id: 2, label: "Ruby"},
      {id: 3, label: "Scala"},
      {id: 4, label: "Scheme"}
    ];
    availableTags2 = [
      {value: 1, label: "ActionScript"},
      {value: 2, label: "Ruby"},
      {value: 3, label: "Scala"},
      {value: 4, label: "Scheme"}
    ];
    $( "#a" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#tosend').val(ui.item.id);
      }
    });
    $( "#b" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags2
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
id to send<br>
<input type="text" name="tosend" id="tosend"><br><br>
type below<br>
<input id="a"><br>
<br>
<br>
using value instead of id<br>
<input id="b">
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about your back-end. But assuming it is accepting IDs for your search parameters, will changing the `source` value to `sellersID` resolve your issue? You also have that extra comma after sources. It will cause you problems.

```
$("#searchSeller").autocomplete({
  messages: {
    noResults: 'No sellers with this ID.',        
  },
  minLength: 2,
  delay: 500,
  source: sellersID
});
```